# Why inline objects are not constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Using [this](https://gist.github.com/oliora/928424f7675d58fadf49c70fdba70d2f) constexpr assert function, objects can't be compiled at build time if they are constexpr.

However, with inline objects, the assertion is fired at run time instead of build time (see below code).

In main function, the first object can't be compiled (as expected).
The second object is compiled, but execution is aborted at run time (as expected).
But the third object is compiled, when the compiler shouldn't allow it.

This means that inline objects are not constexpr?
In this case, is there a way to make inline objects constexpr?

```
#include <cassert>
#include <utility>

// constexpr assert. Sources:
// https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/05/18/asserts-in-constexpr-functions/
// https://gist.github.com/oliora/928424f7675d58fadf49c70fdba70d2f

template<class Assert>
void _constexpr_assert_failed(Assert&& a) noexcept
{
    std::forward<Assert>(a)();
}

// When evaluated at compile time emits a compilation error if condition is not true.
// Invokes the standard assert at run time.
#define FOO_ASSERT(cond) \
        ((void)((cond) ? 0 : (_constexpr_assert_failed([](){ assert(! bool(#cond)); }), 0)))

template<typename Type>
constexpr const Type& assertRange(const Type& value, const Type& minimum, const Type& maximum) noexcept
{
    return FOO_ASSERT(value >= minimum && value <= maximum),
           value;
}

struct Color
{
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;

    constexpr Color(float r, float g, float b) noexcept :
        r(assertRange(r, 0.0f, 1.0f)),
        g(assertRange(g, 0.0f, 1.0f)),
        b(assertRange(b, 0.0f, 1.0f))
    {
    }
};

Color foo(const Color& color)
{
    return Color(color.r * 0.5f, color.g * 0.5f, color.b * 0.5f);
}

int main()
{
    // Build time error:
    // constexpr Color constexprBadColor(10, 0, 0);

    // Run time error:
    // Color runtimeBadColor(10, 0, 0);

    // Run time error?
    foo(Color(10, 0, 0));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What object, `foo`? What is an inline object according to you?

Comment: It's unlikely add is happening at compile time. What is currently happening? What do you expect to happen? How can you demonstrate that in your question?

Comment: `constexpr` is only used in required const expression.

Comment: Why do you think it's not constexpr?

Comment: I have rewritten the question.

Comment: There are no inline variables in this code. And there is no such thing as "inline object".

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what behaviour you expected for each of the first three attempted statements of `main`?

Comment: I have edited the question again. Sorry for not being more clear before. How do you call objects without name? Rvalue objects? Inplace objects?